# Should different muscles be stretched with different amounts of time?

Tags: muscle, stretching

Should different muscles be stretched with different amounts of time?

The following exercise mat seems to advise so:

[image]

If so, what is the scientific consensus on the stretching time for each main muscle group?

Comment: Interesting. I don't recall any studies on different lengths of time *per muscle group*. Most that I've seen focused on the general time per stretch regardless of muscle group.